# Random line when resizing image via function?

Tags: objective-c, uiimagejpegrepresentation

After a user picks a image, it gets saved to their phone and stored like this:

```
// When a user selects a image
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
[picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

int orient = image.imageOrientation;
NSString *theOrientation = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", orient];
NSString *latestIDQuery = @"";
NSArray *results = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM images WHERE status!='uploaded' ORDER BY identifier DESC LIMIT 0,1"]; 
for (NSDictionary *row in results) {
    latestIDQuery = [row objectForKey:@"id"];
}

int latestID = [latestIDQuery intValue];
int newID = latestID + 1;

NSString *newIDString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", newID];
NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@_process.jpg",newIDString];

// Upload image and insert into database
NSString *uploadImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_process.jpg",newIDString];
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageURL];

float tooBig = 800.0;
UIImage *tempImage = [self scaleImage:image:tooBig:tooBig];

[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:NO];
NSString *theID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newID];

[database executeNonQuery:@"INSERT INTO images (id, thumbnail, album, status, orient, ready) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'uploading', ?, 'no');", theID, uploadImagePath, selectedID, theOrientation];

NSString *onestatus;
NSArray *getAlbumID = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM images"];
for (NSDictionary *getAlbumIDRow in getAlbumID) {
    NSString *oneid = [getAlbumIDRow objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *onethumb = [getAlbumIDRow objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    NSString *onestatus = [getAlbumIDRow objectForKey:@"status"];
}

TableViewAppDelegate *dataCeter = (TableViewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
dataCeter.dataSix = nil;
NSString *databaseURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_process.jpg",newIDString];
dataCeter.dataSix = databaseURL;

[newIDString release];
[self presentModalViewController:captionView animated:NO];  
}
```

However, it saves it with a white border on a random side. Below is a example how it look (added a black background to make it more apparent).

I have narrowed it down to my resizing code:

```
// How to scale the image
- (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *) image: (float)maxWidth:(float) maxHeight {

CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

if (width <= maxWidth && height <= maxHeight)
{
    return image;
}

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

if (width > maxWidth || height > maxHeight)
{
    CGFloat ratio = width/height;
    if (ratio > 1)
    {
        bounds.size.width = maxWidth;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
    }
    else
    {
        bounds.size.height = maxHeight;
        bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
    }
}

CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return imageCopy;
}
```

Please help, Thanks.

[White line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT3jw.jpg)

Comment: Use imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: instead of – imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:. What is source of images?

Comment: @TheBlack  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera or UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary. Library for this picture.

Comment: Also, please see my updates. Thanks!

Comment: use scale method from answer. Also check if you get any errors in console after this line.  [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:NO]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation: Just pass scale value calculated in your resize method.

```
- (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *) image: (float)maxWidth:(float) maxHeight {

CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

if (width <= maxWidth && height <= maxHeight)
{
    return image;
}

CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

if (width > maxWidth || height > maxHeight)
{
CGFloat ratio = width/height;
if (ratio > 1)
{
    bounds.size.width = maxWidth;
    bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
}
else
{
    bounds.size.height = maxHeight;
    bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
}

CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef scale:scaleRatio orientation:image. imageOrientation];
```

}

Comment: JK, I replaced `image.orientation` with `image.imageOrientation` and it works. thanks so much!